# Acceleration, Distance, Integration - How to?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, physics, self-learning, education

> At $t = 0$, a particle starts at rest and moves along a line in such a way that, at time $t$, its acceleration is $24\,t^2 \,\, ft/s^2$. Through how many feet does the particle move during the first $2$ seconds?

I was given this problem and I don't know how to solve it. I know it has to do with derivatives etc, I just don't know how to do these questions. I am not asking for the solution - just what are these kinds of problems called and where can I find more practice?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the acceleration is time-varying. The speed at $t$ is obtained via the integral,

$$v(t) = \int_0^t a(s)ds=
\int _0^t 24s^2ds=8t^3$$

Then, the displacement at $t=2$ is

$$\int_0^2 v(t)dt = 
\int_0^2 8t^3dt $$

Comment: So acceleration is the derivative of speed?

Comment: Is there anything else that continues in this chain?

Comment: Oh - speed is the derivative of position?

Comment: @Burt - right, displacement, speed and acceleration are the fundamental measures of kinetic movements. Usually, these are enough for most problems. There is no need to go up and down the chain.

Comment: So these are the big three.

Comment: @Burt - they are the most relevant and important